# Set positon of the markerInfoWindow in Google Maps IOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

i am working on the maps application that requires to use the custom popup.i have added the custom view but i am not able to set the position of the custom popup

here is my code

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {

UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 156, 36)];
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:view.frame];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"markerBg.png"]];
[view addSubview:imgView];

UIImageView *imgRightArrow=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 13, 8, 10)];
[imgRightArrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow1.png"]];
[view addSubview:imgRightArrow];


UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 110, 36)];
[lbl setText:marker.title];
[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lbl setTextColor:[Utility getColor:@"00AAE8"]];
[lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]];
[view addSubview:lbl];




return view;
```

}

[image: Result image]
[image: Original imahe]

Answer (score 0):

Please file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request).